# Running scheduled task on remote server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, scheduled-task

We have 3 scheduled tasks that run on a server.  Randomly someone in HR will ask us to run one of these tasks for them out of schedule.  To make this easier and more expedient for the HR folks, i'm using PowerShell to run the task.  But this only works if i give a user local admin permissions on the server.

We don't want end users having local admin rights obviously.

So i've searched google on this for a while now, found a few posts in various forums with ideas that worked for some people, but so far nothing has worked on my issue.  In testing this, i've given my test account read/write access to the Windows\Tasks folder, added added it to the WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ group (had to create it manually), the Performance Monitor group, Power Users, Users, Remote Desktop Users, and Remote Management Users groups.

Nothing so far has worked, it keeps failing with this error -

```
Start-ScheduledTask : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The WMI service returned an 'access denied' error.
```

My script -

```
$server = "Test_Server"
$task = "Name_of_Task"

Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task -CimSession $server
```

Gotta be something simple i'm missing.

Ideas?

Comment: Don't have any answers for your problem, but for delegating ability to trigger scheduled tasks I setup a Rundeck server.  I found it was generally user and gave me more flexibility.  Though it does have a learning curve to get started.

Answer (score 0):

This might seems super complicated at first, but PowerShell role capabilities is the way to go.  With this tech you can allow a specific user or group to connect to a custom PowerShell session and be able to run a very limited set of commands with a limited set of parameters.  Here is a link to the MS Docs, but if you need more help I can guide you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-5.1